# Textblob module not being found in pyspark dataproc cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, nltk, textblob, dataproc

Im using Dataproc cloud for spark computing. The problem is that my working nodes dont have access to textblob package. How can I fix it?
I'm coding in jupyter notebook with pyspark kernel

Code error:

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 588, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 447, in read_udfs
    udfs.append(read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf, udf_index=i))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 249, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 160, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 430, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'
```

Example code that fails:

```
data = [{"Category": 'Aaaa'},
        {"Category": 'Bbbb'},
        {"Category": 'Cccc'},
        {"Category": 'Eeeee'}
        ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

def sentPackage(text):
    import textblob
    return TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity


sentPackageUDF = udf(sentPackage, StringType(), )
df = df.withColumn("polarity", sentPackageUDF(f.col("Category")))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to define a function that will be sent to the workers and import textblob inside there

```
def function_to_be_executed_by_workers(...):
    import textblob
    # use textblob and perform operations on data
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've edited the post and included code that im currently using - including the import.

Comment: Try to launch your process from a shell (e.g. via ssh) with spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your libraries to the SparkContext, which makes it available to all worker nodes.

Create a folder of any name to store your libraries that you want the worker nodes to access

```
mkdir dependencies
```

Navigate to that folder and copy the libraries in it using `pip`

```
pip download textblob -d .
pip .. .. ..
```

Zip dependencies

```
zip -r dependencies.zip .
```

add `textblob` to the SparkContext

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    ...
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("dependencies.zip")
```